# InvokeonMainThread commands are not running

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, task, ui-thread

i'm having a problem invoking a UIThread in PCL.

I did one method like this:

```
       private async void PopulateContent ()
        {

            Task <List <Department>> taskDep = new Task <List<Department>> (() =>
            {
                departments = departmentDal.GetAll();
                return departments.ToList ();
            });
            TaskDep.Start();
            TaskDep.Wait();
            
            PopulateCarouselDeps();

            Task <List<Category>> taskCat = new Task <List <Category>> (() =>
            {
                Categories = categoryDal.GetAllByDepartment (carouselViewDepartments.Item as Department).ToList ();
                return categories.ToList();
            });
            
            TaskCat.Start();
            TaskCat.Wait();
            PopulateCarouselCats();
            Task <List<Product>> taskProd = new Task <List<Product>> (() =>
            {
                Products = productDal.GetAllByCategory (carouselViewCategories.Item Category);
                return products.ToList();
            });
            TaskProd.Start();
            TaskProd.Wait();
            PopulateListViewProducts();
        }

    private void PopulateCarouselDeps ()
    {
            
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
                Try
                {
                    carouselViewDepartments.ItemsSource = departments;
                }
                Catch (Exception e) // handle whatever exceptions you expect
                {
                    // Handle exceptions
                }
            });
    }
```

What happens is the following, when I invoke the PopulateCarouselDeps() method it just does not get into the try-catch statement block.

Consequently the Carousel is not populated and I need it to popularize the other contents.

All popular methods are very similar.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thx,

Comment: Return a Task instead of void and put the call in try & catch for PopulateContent.

Comment: Okay, I'll try, but if I return a single Task, my Category data is dependent on the Department data being populated, will not this generate inconsistency? Thx for help.

Comment: I meant 'private async void PopulateContent()' to 'private async Task PopulateContent()'.

Comment: I did this. What is happening is that the commands inside the BeginInvokeOnMainThread are not running, when the compiler reads the method it ignores and goes to the next statement.

Comment: Did you try to put a breakpoint inside PopulateCarouselDeps? Where the execution 'stops'?

Comment: Yes, I put a breakpoint on the first line of the method. Execution stops when the PopulateCarouselCats method is invoked because it needs the carouseldep data. So I need the task to be executed method by method.

Comment: Someone else can help me?